# Send large files over HTTP requests

Tags: java, http

I searched for, "Transfer large file in Java" and got myriad results centered around the use of Sockets to achieve the same except the constraint in my case is to use a HTTP request purely to achieve the same.

Is there any way I can send a large file over HTTP to the server so that even if the Network connection breaks, I am able to resume sending the file the *next time*.

Is there any technique to achieve the same...perhaps something in the HTTP spec itself. If not, I am ready to do take manual approach too whatsoever.

---

**EDIT:** In response to question being *too broad*, I would like to state that I want to accomplish the same on Android(Java) and PHP(server side)

Comment: Yes, use HTTP range requests: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests

Comment: @jim-garrison, see the edit for *Too broad*

Comment: As explained in the [tour], this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers, ***not a help forum***.  
Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and especially read [ask] and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157) to learn how to use this site effectively.  The edit does nothing to make this on-topic.

Comment: @Rishav But that's for requesting large content "from" the server. I intend to send large content "to" the server